# How to create a Google Analytics Filter that includes 2 host names?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

My goal is to create a Google Analytics filter that "includes only" 2 host names.

For example, include only:

- www.example.com
- www2.example.com

The desired result is that Google Analytics reports display traffic only from www.example.com and www2.example.com.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you mark the question correct if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this by seperating sources with pipe "|"

```
example\.com|example2\.com|.*example3\.com
```

Here is Google documentation:

> Include Filters are applied with the reverse logic. When you apply an
>   Include Filter, the hit is thrown away if the pattern does not match
>   the data. If you apply multiple Include Filters, the hit must match
>   every applied Include Filter in order to save the hit. To include
>   multiple patterns for a specific field, create a single include filter
>   that contains all of the individual expressions separated by '|'.

Check these links for more information

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en